# The converse of $\exists\alpha>1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}: |x|^\alpha |f(x)| <c \implies \int |f|dx <\infty$

Tags: integration

It is easy to show, that (for continuous functions f)
 $$\exists c>0,\exists\alpha>1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}: |x|^\alpha |f(x)| <c \implies \int |f|dx <\infty$$

The question is, whether or not this is also a neccessary condition. I could not come up with any counterexamples ($1/(x \log x)$ is not integrable yet). But I am also not able to prove it. And it is difficult to search for even though someone has probably already asked this question.

---

UPDATE: It appears this is not true in general even for smooth functions $f\in C^\infty$ due to the ability to create smooth bumps of fixed hight in regular intervals with a decreasing base, making them integrable (See comments and answers). So in order to avoid that: what about monotonous functions?

I am trying to understand wether or not there is a function with a decrease "between" $1/x$ and $1/x^\alpha$. Sorry for moving the goalposts.

---

Proof, that it is sufficient:
$$\int |f(x)| dx \le \int_{|x|<1} |f(x)| dx + \int_{|x|>1} |x|^{-\alpha}|x|^\alpha |f(x)|dx<2\|f\|_{\infty,[-1,1]} + c\int_{|x|>1} |x|^{-\alpha}dx<\infty$$

Fix due to the helpful question whether or not $|x|^{-\alpha}$ is integrable.

Comment: I think if you pick an $f$ with that propery and modify it so that $f(n) \to +\infty$ with the appropriate speed, it will not have that property, but the integral will be finite because $\mathbb{N}$ is a measure zero set.

Comment: No, you can have an integrable  function $f$ with thin "spikes" infinitely often.

Comment: Hm good points, so what about continuous f?

Comment: U might want to take a look at the contradiction $|f(x)| \geq \frac{c}{|x|^\alpha}$ for  $\alpha \rightarrow  1$.

Comment: Why $\int |x|^{-\alpha}dx<\infty$ ? Isn't $\int_0^1 x^{-2}\;dx = +\infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were, then $|f(x)|<c/|x|^{\alpha}$ for $|x|>1$ which entails that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. So we are asking whether integrable functions will eventually converge to zero, there are plenty of counterexamples.

One counterexample would be, $f(x)=1$ for $n\leq x\leq n+1/2^{n}$ and zero otherwise.

For the updated question, take $f(x)=1/(2(\log 2)^{2})$ for $0\leq x\leq 2$ and $f(x)=1/(x(\log x)^{2})$ for $x\geq 2$, and for $x<0$, make it as an even function.

So $f\in L^{1}({\mathbb{R}})$. If there were some $C>0$ and $\alpha>1$ such that $x^{\alpha}f(x)\leq C$ for all $x\geq 2$, then $x^{\alpha-1}/(\log x)^{2}\leq C$. But we can have $\log x\leq C'x^{(\alpha -1)/4}$, then $x^{\alpha -1}/(\log x)^{2}\geq C''x^{(\alpha-1)/2}$. Taking limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$ gives you a contradiction.

Comment: Even you require that the continuity in question, the similar counterexample can be produced. You can take a smooth bump on $[n,n+1/2^{n}]$ which is no higher than $1$.

Comment: And the counterexample will even stop you to think about $C^{\infty}$ functions.

Comment: hm, monotonous functions?

Comment: What about $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x(\log x)^{2}}$?

Answer (score 0):

A better example than my measure-zero one in the comment: Pick your favorite summable sequence $(a_n)$ and your favorite positive number $b$, and construct a function whose grap has a right triangle with base $a_n$ and height $b$. It's integral will be $\sum_n a_n b/2 <+\infty$, but it does not go to zero at infinity.